# How to get the setText value in Textbox Entry when Button is clicked in Page GUI python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have used `Page GUI Builder` for constructing `GUI` and I have created one `button(alias:Button1)` and one `TextBox(alias:Text1`). I want that when I click button  some text which I have define like "Hello World" be displayed inside text Box.

Actually, I have had problem related to binding the button and textbox defined with a builder with the text I want to display.

**Note:** I am searching for a solution where I am integrating GUI through `Page Builder`.

```
import sys

try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as tk

try:
  import ttk
  py3 = False
except ImportError:
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk
  py3 = True

import UI_support

def vp_start_gui():
'''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
  global val, w, root
  root = tk.Tk()
  top = Toplevel1 (root)
  UI_support.init(root, top)
  root.mainloop()

  w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
'''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
  global w, w_win, rt
  rt = root
  w = tk.Toplevel (root)
  top = Toplevel1 (w)
  UI_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
  return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
  global w
  w.destroy()
  w = None

class Toplevel1:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
    '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
       top is the toplevel containing window.'''
    _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
    _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
    _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92' 

    top.geometry("600x450+1085+305")
    top.title("New Toplevel")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

    self.Button1 = tk.Button(top)
    self.Button1.place(relx=0.417, rely=0.311, height=33, width=56)
    self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
    self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
    self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
    self.Button1.configure(text='''Button''')

    self.Text1 = tk.Text(top)
    self.Text1.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.133, relheight=0.12, relwidth=0.323)
    self.Text1.configure(background="white")
    self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
    self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
    self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(width=194)
    self.Text1.configure(wrap='word')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  vp_start_gui()
```

and then a UI_support.py

```
import sys

try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as tk

try:
  import ttk
  py3 = False
except ImportError:
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk
  py3 = True

def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
  global w, top_level, root
  w = gui
  top_level = top
  root = top

def destroy_window():
# Function which closes the window.
  global top_level
  top_level.destroy()
  top_level = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import UI
  UI.vp_start_gui()
```

If I can define a class in UI.py for showing text in textbox when button is clicked or will create a new .py file and import it.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of what you have to do is to define a function (to print the message) and then activate that function by calling it with `command=(functionname)` in your button.

So your function may look something like this:

```
def show_text():
    print("Hello World!")
```

and your button would be akin to:

```
Button1 = tk.Button((pos), text="Hello", command=show_text) #position can be top/bottom/left or right
```

You can use a tkinter message box (as opposed to creating a text box from scratch) to display your message if you want. It may make things simpler? You would have to import the tkMessageBox

A short code example of this (some lines you already have in your code, e.g. imports):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

top = tk.Tk()

def msg_text():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Hello!", "Hello World") #arguments are title, message

Button1 = tk.Button(top, text ="Hello!", command = msg_text)

Button1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

You haven't set any default text in your textbox (e.g. text.insert(INSERT, "Your text here"). You could write a function to set this configuration on click either 
e.g.

```
def onclick():
    Text1.config(text='Hello World')
```

Hope this assists you

Comment: My button and text box are already defined in UI.py file.I want to add this functionality.I am unable to process the (self.button1) with the function I want to define.I know the creation part for defining.I have problem with binding with the UI previously defined by GUI builder.