# How to get the text in textbox when button is clicked in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick, buttonclick

I have defined a method called changeText() which will display "Hello" on Button Click and I have called it in Button.
But still I am not able to get the text in Textbox whose alias is TextBox1 and have called the method in Button whose alias is Button1 but still I have  not got result.

I have two files: Button.py

```
import sys

try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as tk

try:
  import ttk
  py3 = False
except ImportError:
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk
  py3 = True

import Button_support

def vp_start_gui():
  '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
  global val, w, root
  root = tk.Tk()
  top = Toplevel1 (root)
  Button_support.init(root, top)
  root.mainloop()

  w = None
def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
'''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
  global w, w_win, rt
  rt = root
  w = tk.Toplevel (root)
  top = Toplevel1 (w)
  Button_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
  return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
  global w
  w.destroy()
  w = None

class Toplevel1:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
    '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
       top is the toplevel containing window.'''
    _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
    _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
    _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
    _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92' 

    top.geometry("600x450+639+258")
    top.title("New Toplevel")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

#this is defined method and I have called in button

    def changeText():     
        self.Text1.insert(END,"hyyyy")  


    self.Button1 = tk.Button(top,command=changeText)
    self.Button1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.289, height=33, width=56)
    self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
    self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
    self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
    self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
    self.Button1.configure(text='''Button''')

    self.Text1 = tk.Text(top)
    self.Text1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.089, relheight=0.12, relwidth=0.29)
    self.Text1.configure(background="white")
    self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
    self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
    self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
    self.Text1.configure(width=174)
    self.Text1.configure(wrap='word')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  vp_start_gui()
```

Another file is: Button_support.py

```
import sys

try:
  import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import tkinter as tk

try:
  import ttk
  py3 = False
except ImportError:
  import tkinter.ttk as ttk
  py3 = True

def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
  global w, top_level, root
  w = gui
  top_level = top
  root = top

def destroy_window():
  # Function which closes the window.
  global top_level
  top_level.destroy()
  top_level = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import Button
  Button.vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: **EXACT** duplicate of [how-to-get-the-settext-value-in-textbox-entry-when-button-is-clicked-in-page-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835667/how-to-get-the-settext-value-in-textbox-entry-when-button-is-clicked-in-page-gui)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to display the text in the textbox when the button is clicked:

[image: Image of user's program]

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? You didn't mention if you were getting any errors, but I did discover two issues with your code:

- There seem to be some indentation issues in the `Button.py` script.
- For `self.Text1.insert(END,"hyyyy")` in your `changeText()` method, instead of `END`, you probably want `tk.END` (e.g., `self.Text1.insert(tk.END, "hyyyy")`).

Here is my slightly modified version of your `Button.py` code that seems to run on my end. I didn't make any changes to your `Button_support.py` code.

**Button.py**

```
import sys

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import Button_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    Button_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

    w = None

def create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    Button_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("600x450+639+258")
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        #this is defined method and I have called in button

        def changeText():
            self.Text1.insert(tk.END,"hyyyy")


        self.Button1 = tk.Button(top,command=changeText)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.289, height=33, width=56)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Button''')

        self.Text1 = tk.Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.089, relheight=0.12, relwidth=0.29)
        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=174)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap='word')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify what behavior you are expecting and I will attempt to modify my answer accordingly.